# php live document error

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have the following code I have thrown together for a sort of live document per say in php, and html. It worked yesterday, but for some strange reason today It decided not to work. It was meant to save a file to server(.txt) and also display that file. here is my code:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <form name="savefile" method="post" action="">
 <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="code"><br/>
        <textarea rows="16" cols="100" name="textdata">
      <?php 
    $text = file_get_contents('user.txt');
    echo $text;
?>
  </textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submitsave" value="Save">
</form>
    File Contents:<br/>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST)){
        if ($_POST['submitsave'] == "Save"  && !empty($_POST['filename'])) {
            if(!file_exists($_POST['filename'] . ".txt")){
                $file = tmpfile();
            }
            $file = fopen($_POST['filename'] . ".txt","a+");
            while(!feof($file)){
                $old = $old . fgets($file). "<br />";
            }
            $text = $_POST["textdata"];
            file_put_contents($_POST['filename'] . ".txt", $old . $text);
            fclose($file);
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is a php file btw
the php in the textarea works, but the php that saves the text to the serverside is broken.
this is my error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /homepages/31/d585123241/htdocs/test/red.php on line 27**

Comment: it says error on line 27

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: i put it in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last if is not closed. Add another }

Comment: please specify a more advanced answer

Comment: well it worked so.... now I know that error